# URL rewriting in WordPress not using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a URL in WordPress.

The structure is `/car/123/bmw-series-A` where pagename is `car`, carID is `123` and modelName is `bmw-series-A`.

There is a custom template where I will be getting the carID and modelName.

I have the following code:

functions.php

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('car/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=car&carID=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');


function prefix_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'carID';
    $vars[] = 'modelName';
    return $vars;
}
 
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var' );
```

I get the carID in the custom template but not the modelName when I try adding modelName it goes to the 404 page.

Code:

```
$aNewRules = array('car/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=car&carID=$matches[1]&modelName=$matches[2]');
```

Comment: Just want to confirm you have flushed the re-write rules?

Comment: @mikerojas Yes worked after saving the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a rule for both paths... update `add_rewrite_rules` like below:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules)
{
  // id rule
  $aNewRules = array('car/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=car&carID=$matches[1]');

  // model rule
  $bNewRules = array('car/([\w+]*)/([\w+]*)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=car&carID=$matches[1]&modelName=$matches[2]');

  $aRules = $aNewRules + $bNewRules + $aRules;

  return $aRules;
}
```